# Need help taking a screenshot during Keynote presentation

Tags: screen-capture, keynote

I know Cmd+Shift+4 is how screenshots are normally taken of visible areas on Mac OS X, but this shortcut does not work during a Keynote Presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS X has a command-line tool called screencapture that makes a screenshot. Try this:

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `screencapture -T 5 -t tiff ~/Desktop/screenshot.png` (the "-T 5" option specifies a 5-second delay; the "-t tiff" option specifies saving the data in the uncompressed tiff image format)
3. Hide Terminal and return to Keynote within 5 seconds

With a full-screen screenshot, you can use the crop tool in Preview.app to save the region of the screen that you want.

Comment: This is useful but I want to keep the high resolution of the graphics I used on the presentation. Do you know how to take screenshots on secondary displays? Thank you!

Comment: You can save the screen capture in an uncompressed tiff format by using the option "-t tiff". I'll edit the command above to include this option. Regarding secondary displays, I don't know for sure and I can't test it right now, but the man page (accessible by typing "man screencapture" in Terminal) suggests that all of the available screens will be captured. But I don't understand how that works since only one filename is provided on the command-line.

Comment: There's a GUI for that functionality called Grab in /Applications/Utilities.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can export a Keynote presentation in a number of formats, including jpg, tiff and png–no need for screenshots.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> snaps a picture of te selected portion of a screen, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> is the shortcut for a full screenshot.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I also found out that if you are connected to a secondary display, Cmd Shift 3 takes screenshots of both displays at the same time so you end up with 2 pngs.